# Foreach loop only acting on a portion of the first element in an array

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, foreach

I have five fasta files in a directory, which I can successfully put into an array. When I attempt to open all the files in succession via a foreach loop, to perform a regex on each file, only the first file in the directory seems to open for processing. Furthermore, when I try to print the entire sequence in the first file (via a diagnostic print statement not shown), the first half of the sequence is ignored. Only the latter portion of the sequence is printed. If anyone has insights on how to overcome this, I would be very grateful. Here is what my code looks like so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings; 
use strict;
use diagnostics; 

my $dir = ("/Users/roblogan/Documents/FakeFastaFilesAgain");  
my @TrimmedSequences; 

my @ArrayofFiles = glob "$dir/*"; 

#print join("\n", @ArrayofFiles), "\n";      # this is a diagnostic test print statement

foreach my $file (@ArrayofFiles){ 
    open (my $sequence, '<', $file) or die $!; # open each file in the array
    while (my $line = <$sequence>) {  
        $line =~ s/\R//g;                          # get rid of new line breaks
        if ($line =~ m/(CTCCCA)[TAGC]+(TCAGGA)/) { # search file contents 
            push(@TrimmedSequences, $line);        # push the match into another array 
            close $file; 
        }
    }
}   

print join("\n", @TrimmedSequences), "\n";
```

Comment: `close $file` won't be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing your code (or similar to it) works fine when removing the close statement. Using the close breaks the loop as soon as it finds a match. Leaving only one result per file.

Also note, you don't need to call close at all. The file will be closed when the variable $sequence loses scope.

`chomp` should be used to get rid of newlines

Here is my test code. note a few edits.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $files = (".");

my @files = grep { $_ =~ /\.pl/} glob "$files/*"; #added to filter out the directies in test directory, can be ignored
my @lines;

#use for in perl not foreach
for my $file (@files){
  open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;
  while(my $line = <$fh>){
    chomp($line); #Use chomp to remove newlines
    if($line =~ /use/){
      push @lines, $line; #no need to call close at all, the filehandle is closed when it loses scope
    }
  }
}

print join("\n", @lines) . "\n";
```

Does as expected in my test directory and prints all the use statements from the perl files I have in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling close on the wrong variable `$file` (filename, a string) instead of `$sequence` (the filehandle of the file).

Also, the `close` call is in the wrong place, you are closing the filehandle in the middle of the read loop. If you really intended to find only the first matching line in each file, close the filehandle and break (`last`) out of the while loop. If you want to find all matching lines in all files:

```
foreach my $file (@ArrayofFiles){ 
    open (my $sequence, '<', $file) or die $!;
    while (my $line = <$sequence>) {  
        $line =~ s/\R//g;
        if ($line =~ m/(CTCCCA)[TAGC]+(TCAGGA)/) {
            push(@TrimmedSequences, $line);
        }
    }
    close $sequence or die $!; 
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, even after experimenting with all your answers, I still am only able to read in, operate on, and print one file out of the directory of files. I should at least be able to add all of the contents of the files in turn to an array and then print them out. Playing with the close statement didn't help with this. At minimum the following code should be functional, but isn't: foreach my $file (@ArrayofFiles) { open (my $sequence, '<', $file) or die $!; while (my $line = <$sequence>){ chomp($line); push(@TrimmedSequences, $line); }} print @trimmedSequences, "\n";

Comment: @Rob try making a script with the minimal amount of code needed to print all lines from one of the files. Sounds like it isn't so much a problem with this block of code, maybe there is something elsewhere in your code, or something to do with the files you're trying to parse